# hours:minutes:seconds Timestamp regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to validate a user inputed video timestamp in the format `hours:minutes:seconds` using a regex. So I'm assuming the hours component can be arbitrarily long, so the final format is basically `hhhh:mm:ss` where there can be any number of `h`. This is what I have so far

```regex
(([0-9]+:)?([0-5][0-9]:))?([0-5][0-9])
```

where

```sh
(
  ([0-9]+:)?    # hh: optionally with an arbitrary number of h
  ([0-5][0-9]:) # mm: , with mm from 00 to 59
)?              # hh:mm optionally
([0-5][0-9])    # ss , wtih ss from 00 to 59
```

which I believe is almost there, but doesn't handle cases like `1:31` or just `1`. So to account for this if I add the first digit inside the `mm` and `ss` blocks as optional,

```regex
(([0-9]+:)?([0-5]?[0-9]:))?([0-5]?[0-9])
```

firstly the last seconds block starts matching values like `111`. Also values like `1:1:12` are matched , which I don't want (should be `1:01:12`). So how can I modify this so that `m:ss` and `s` are valid whereas `h:m:ss`,`m:s` and `sss` are not?

I am new to regular expressions, so apologies in advance if I'm doing something stupid. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You want `1:01:12` to match, but not `1:1:12` - but also you want `m:ss` to be possible? All those `?` make a lot optional which is then valid. I would let the regex do the parsing part and use comparison operators to validate if its a time. As a regex puzzle, sure. But not really worth the time.

Comment: Ah okay. Perhaps I should consider implementing it like that. If the regex needs to be too complicated, it's probably more trouble than it is worth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match either 1 or more digits followed by an optional `:mm:ss` part, or match `mm:ss`.

To also match `6:12` and not `1:1:12` make only the first digit optional in the second part of the pattern.

```
^(?:\d+(?::[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])?|[0-5]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9])$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\d+` Match 1+ digits
  - `(?::[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])?` Match an optional `:mm:ss` part, both in range 00 - 59
  - `|` Or
  - `[0-5]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]` Match `m:ss` or `mm:ss` both in range 00-59 where the first m is optional
- `)` Close non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UnvAIW/1)

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. This is really close, but I was expecting to match `m:ss` as well. Which i guess is the tricky part. I was hoping to match `m:ss` but not match to `h:m:ss` and only to `h:mm:ss`. In your example match to `6:12` but without matching to `1:1:12` as well in the process

Comment: @phoney_badger Like this? https://regex101.com/r/L35Myo/1

Comment: Yeah that was the case I wanted. Thanks. Actually I was hoping that the default value would be `s` or `ss` instead of the hours value, like `1234` wouldn't be valid. But this also works. I'm sure I can tweak this and make it work.

Comment: @phoney_badger The `\d+` at the start of the pattern matches the first digits, you can make the pattern more specific to allow which digits/range you want to allow.

Comment: Yep got it. I can work with this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't adding the positional anchors(`^` and `$`)solve your problem?

```
^(([0-9]+:)?([0-5][0-9]:))?([0-5][0-9])$
```

Check here: https://regex101.com/r/fRZf2R/1

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I guess it solves the first part of the problem. i.e. matching of `sss`. But it doesn't match `m:ss` or `s`, say `6:12` or `3`, which I want it to match.